# how to groupby duplicate values but retain other columns of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to groupby duplicate values of a dataframe column but also retain the other column of the dataframe after the groupby. 
For example the data looks like:
df-

```
id     interest   location
1        A            X
2        A            Y
1        B            X
3        C            Z
2        D            Y
```

The output should be

```
id     interest      location
1        A,B            X
2        A,D            Y
3        C              Z
```

The following code gives just the id and interest column however I want to get the corresponding user's location too.

`unique_id = df.groupby('id')['interest'].unique().reset_index()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `groupby.agg`

```
yourdf=df.groupby('id',as_index=False).agg({'interest':','.join,'location':'first'})
yourdf
Out[140]: 
   id interest location
0   1      A,B        X
1   2      A,D        Y
2   3        C        Z
```

Comment: what if i want the combined interests in lists like[A,B] or [one,two]

Comment: @user11035754 `df.groupby('id',as_index=False).agg({'interest':lambda x : list(x),'location':'first'})
`

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat clumsy but working solution. Quite similar to what Wen-Ben proposed, except that it works with an arbitrary number of columns, sorts the items before aggregation, and also aggregates locations.

```
result = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x:
                                pd.Series({name: ','.join(sorted(set(x[name]))) 
                                          for name in x})).reset_index()
#   id interest location
#0   1      A,B        X
#1   2      A,D        Y
#2   3        C        Z
```